# How to avoid "overfoldering" when uploading eclipse projects to git?

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

Is there a way to avoid creating an extra folder when exporting Eclipse project to GIT?

[image: extrafolders at target path]

I have already have repository called PikabuMD but Eclipse intends to create another folder with the such name. The point is I can push the whole project folder. Is there a way to share src-folder only? If I name the project src it would be "/amorphine/pikabumd/src/src/", if I leave as it is it will be "/amorphine/pikabumd/pikabumd/src/". The third level at the hierarchy is obviously extra.

Comment: It's generally considered best practice not to keep your project at the root level - which is why eclipse puts the project in a sub directory. Can you elaborate on why you want it at the top level?

Comment: @HarryHarrison I'm not sure the issue is the best practice you are talking about. As an example I can take guthub: 'https://github.com/kemiller/tic-tac-toe' - domain-user-repository-source. In my case I get domain-user-repository-extra folder-source

Comment: if this is the best practice, then how come most projects on GitHub and Bitbucket do not follow it? also, why does it make any sense to have the extra folder? no one keeps more than one project per git repo these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EGit highly recommends against putting the .project file in the root of the Git repository, so I would not expect EGit to have much support for it.

From the [manual](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.egit.doc/help/EGit/User_Guide/Tasks.html?cp=19_0_2):

> Don't create a Repository with an Eclipse project as root.

So, if you really really want to do it anyway, do it manually:

1. Delete project in Eclipse
2. Move the project contents to your Git repository
3. Import the project (choose method a or b)

   a. From Git view in Git perspective by

   1. Right-clicking on the Git repository
   2. Choose *Import Projects...*
   3. Complete the wizard

   b. From the Import menu

   1. From *File* menu, choose *Import...*
   2. Choose *General* / *Existing Project into Workspace*
   3. Complete the wizard